# Deep Packet Inspection with mTLS

Tags: networking, pci-compliance, mtls

Greetings and happy Friday!

I have somewhat of an interesting question for the networking and/or GRC Junkies in the room...

I have a customer who has a requirement for:

- Mutual TLS (mTLS) on outbound connections to certain partners.
- Deep Packet Inspection on outbound connections to perform DLP scanning.

For the life of me I can't find any vendors that support this... But there has to be someone doing this somewhere if they have the requirement.

Is anyone here doing this?